# Test for available entry point in native library

Tags: c#, .net, mono, pinvoke

I am developing a cross-platform wrapper for a C library in C#. This library exists in different versions, and they differ by some functions.

In the wrapper I want to enable these functions, if they are available.

For using it in C, there is a documentation on how to test for these functions:
http://jackaudio.org/api/group__WeakLinkage.html, i.e

```
if (jack_set_latency_callback) {
   jack_set_latency_callback (jill_client, jill_latency_callback, arg);
}
```

My C# wrapper is defined as

```
[DllImport (Constants.JACK_LIB_NAME, 
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, 
    EntryPoint = "jack_set_latency_callback")]
public static extern unsafe int SetLatencyCallback (UnsafeStructs.jack_client_t* client, 
    Callbacks.JackLatencyCallback latencyCallback, 
    IntPtr arg);
```

Now, when I call this function with older unsupported version, I get a `EntryPointNotFoundException` of course. How can I test, if this entry point is available?

This should not only work in Windows, but also with Mono on Linux and Mac OS X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `LoadLibrary` to load the DLL. Then call `GetProcAddress`, passing the module handle returned by `LoadLibrary`, and the entry point name, to test whether or not the named entry point point is exported.

These two functions are documented on MSDN and a websearch will take you to this documentation. The p/invokes are easy enough to write but you may as well use the versions provided by http://pinvoke.net.

In your edit to the question you introduce Mono. Well, the answer is essentially the same, but you use `dlopen` and `dlsym` in place of `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.

Comment: This will work on Windows, but the solution should also work on Linux and Mac with Mono. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: That is not the droid^Wsolution I was looking for, because I want to keep platform specific code down to a minimum.

Comment: Platform specific code is necessary here because you are using different platforms. It's easy enough to wrap this up so that your consuming code does not have to be aware of the platform dependencies. Of course, you could just handle `EntryPointNotFoundException`. Anyway, I'm very sorry that I have not been able to meet your expectations.

Comment: Yes, I know. Maybe some other solution pops up from another user.

Comment: It's quite frustrating to have had the question change twice since I answered it. Just so that you know.